# Does sendBroadcast(Intent i) need to be called from an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcast, android-broadcast

pretty much as it says in the title. I'm trying to send an intent from a timer that is on a daemon thread that will be received by another app. Can I do this or does it need to be called in an activity?

Also is there any way to find out what a class needs to extend or implement without trying to find an example of someone using it.

the code I'm using to call it from inside the `run()` function in my class that extends `TimerTask`

```
    // send info 
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra("MyClass", playing);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call sendBroadcastMethod with any live thread context , Like you have set a timer in a n activity and you are calling the sendBroadcast after 30 seconds , meanwhile you finish the activity by doing onBackPress than it will throw a dead thread error , because you are using 
dead context ( activity in this case) to call the broadcast .
Otherwise you can use any context to call the sendBroadcast method .